# Should I organize my Entity Framework Service Layer in partial classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I am work on a very large project whose Service Layer is currently organized in many service classes that contain the CRUD operations for each database entity. For example, for the entity "Product", we have:

```
public class ProductService
{
    public bool AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        // code omitted
    }

    public bool DeleteProduct(Guid productId)
    {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

And for the entity "User":

```
public class UserService
{
    public bool AddUser(User user)
    {
        // code omitted
    }

    public bool DeleteUser(Guid userId)
    {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

Now, imagine of having dozens of entities like this, all with their own services. Every time you want to manipulate them, you'll have to instantiate all the needed services, so your code will always start with something like this:

```
var productService = new ProductService(); 
var userService = new userService(); 

productService.AddProduct();
userService.AddUser();
```

To me, this looks unnecessary an messy, so I thought: why not having just one class containing all the service methods, maybe split in partial classes to keep it organized? The result would be:

```
public partial class MyService
{
    public bool AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        // code omitted
    }

    public bool DeleteProduct(Guid productId)
    {
        // code omitted
    }
}

public partial class MyService
{
    public bool AddUser(User user)
    {
        // code omitted
    }

    public bool DeleteUser(Guid userId)
    {
        // code omitted
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
var service = new MyService();

service.AddProduct();
service.AddUser();
```

Do you see any downside with this approach? Is there any reason why I shouldn't do this?

Comment: Firstly, this is primarily opinion based so is off-topic for SO. Secondly, my opinion is: don't do this, keep them separate as your suggestion violates the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score -1):

This code you provided seems like an attempt at DDD.

What i recommend you do is read up on CQRS, and then implement a `Handler` class that will take care of a generic `Query<T>` class.

The `Query<T>` can then take care of creating a necessary `DbContext` and `Getting` the data.

Likewise, for `Add` etc. you would have a `Command<T>` class.

The point of it will be that the code will be very small but all the common parts will leave in generic classes resulting in high code reuse and maintainability.

Secondly, in modern .Net (unless you're on Xamarin) you should not write `var x = new Service()` in any code. Read up on dependency injection (Inversion of Control, IoC). This pattern is available for most major platforms for .Net (WPF, ASP .Net, UWP, WinRT etc) and will greatly improve testability of the code.